# What is the difference between GitHub and Bitbuck source repositories?

Tags: github

What is the difference between GitHub and Bitbuck source repositories? Which one is better if I want to share source code privately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitbucket just provides you unlimited git private repositories for free for a five users plan. As they say ***Bitbucket is the Git solution for professional teams***. In GitHub if you require private git repos then you have to purchase a plan for it. The two services have very different billing structures, for example -- GitHub charges per private repo, BitBucket charges per private collaborator.

Also, their issue tracking, wiki, history viewer and collaboration features work pretty differently. GitHub has its own bug tracking system and BitBucket provides JIRA integration.

This image provides the difference in short:

[image]

Answer to you question: ***Which one is better if I want to share source code privately?***

If you don't have many collaborators to add (not more than five) then BitBucket is the best to choose as you will get a free private repo. If you have many collaborators to add on the project then GitHub charges for the repository instead of the number of collaborators.

The rest depends on you to choose what features you require and you may choose according to that.

**Source of Image:** https://www.upguard.com/articles/github-vs-bitbucket

Comment: Thanks Deep for nice explanation.

Comment: +10 nice explanation!